# Discord.py Error 429 Too Many Requests - How to work with? How to fix? - Someone with little knowledge

Tags: python, discord

My bot is being limited with the error code "429 Too Many Requests".
I understand that it makes too many requests, but I don't understand how and my knowledge in Python is really limited.
No one has been running commands on my bot, and the only repetitive command I have running does so once every half hour. Is that really enough to get myself blocked by Discord??

Here's the code part that runs every half hour.

```
async def online_checker():
  await dclient.wait_until_ready()
  channel = dclient.get_channel(id=ID) # Channel ID the Bot will send 30m updates to.

  while not dclient.is_closed():
    session = requests.session()
    s = session.get('ADDRESS')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, 'html.parser')
    jsonString = json.loads(s.text)
    length = len(jsonString)
    keys = db.keys()
    online_list = []
    confirmed_online = []
    for x in range(length):
      online_list.append((jsonString[x]['character_name']))
    for online_compare in online_list:
      for parole_compare in keys:
         if online_compare == parole_compare:
          confirmed_online.append(parole_compare)
          break
    await channel.send('Online: {}'.format(confirmed_online))
    s.close()
    await asyncio.sleep(1800) # How often the bot should check for online
```

What am I doing wrong here? What's causing my bot to be blocked by Discord's API ?
And most importantly, how can I check how many more requests my bot can send without being blocked? I looked through the documentation and I just don't have enough understanding in Python to know what to do with it.

Comment: Is your bot being used in a particularly active server, or a lot of servers?

Comment: Just one server, it's a very specific bot only for our use.
EDIT: It's not particularly active, either. It hasn't received user commands in 2 days and only has been giving out the commands once per 30 minutes listed above.

Comment: It must have been some sort of DDOS attack for discord's API servers. I'm sure one bot wouldn't completely annihilate the platform

Comment: Could it be there's something else in my code causing some sort of loop or issue? 
I really don't know coding at all past the 2 days of Googling I did to make this bot. 

Maybe I put the "while" loop incorrectly or something? There has to be something to have caused this :(

Comment: Your code could only get rate limited if you send out too many requests. This doesn't look like it sends any requests besides the ones for commands.